# Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator empty window

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, microsoft-klc

The [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) doesn't show the keyboard (empty grey screen) or the keys are blank (not labeled).

For example: [image: no keyboard visible]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: This is a very old and outdated software, dating from 2007.

Comment: @harrymc It's quite old but as far as I know not outdated, it's fully functional. According to [the blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20130618134640/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/06/24/10028177.aspx), the problem described here is the only major known one. I'm not aware of better alternative software. If you are, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to "futz with the per-application and overall DPI settings" (note the "and"!).
Source: [this archived blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20130618134640/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/06/24/10028177.aspx) by a developer of MSKLC.

In other words, try at least one of the following:

- "Control Panel" → "Display" → "Set custom text size (DPI)" → change the value a little bit
- Right click on MSKLC.exe → "Compatibility" → modify DPI settings

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by resetting my advanced scaling options to 100%.

In Settings go to Display and select Advanced Scaling Options (highlighted in red):

[image: Windows display settings]

Set scaling to 100%:

[image: Advanced scaling options]